# How does Java's createSymbolicLink method handle non-existent target files?

Tags: java, symlink

In Java's File.class, there's a method called createSymbolicLink(Path link, Path target) that I'm trying to use in a program I'm making.

In the [createSymbolicLink method documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createSymbolicLink-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-), it says it throws a FileAlreadyExistsException if a file with the same Path as the *link* file already exists.

But what if the *target* file **does not** exist? I was testing this, and it seems to run without complaining. However, it just creates useless broken symbolic links. Is there a way to make eclipse catch the fact that the file it is trying to make a symbolic link for does not exist?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Access the symbolic link after to test it? It's *valid* (even if dubious) to create a symbolic link to a non-existent file in many filesystems; and the target may be deleted at any time without affecting the symbolic link itself.

Comment: Oh, I see. I guess I could also use a simple File.exists() check before passing the file to the createSymbolicLink parameters. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: You can do the same thing with `ln -s`. It's not peculiar to Java.